# Jquery Switching browser instances

Tags: jquery, browser, switch-statement

I am using jQuery along with a large number of other jQuery plugins. I have an issue where if I have two instances of Firefox or IE open (in Vista), then when my page loads it automatically switches to the other browers instance (either other FF or other IE). If there isn't a second browser instance then nothing happens.

I have added an alert into

```
jQuery.extend({
   isReady: false,
   readyList: [],
   // Handle when the DOM is ready
   ready: function() {}
});
```

I have put an alert at the end of the ready list and when this alert fires then the instance swtich does not happen.
Any ideas would be great.

To be clear, the instance switch I am talking about is similar to pressing alt-tab.

Regards

John

Comment: How weird. Have you tried this with other browser combinations?

Comment: Nope just FF(latest) and IE (7/8). I can't find any mention of this anywhere on the internet. It's kinda frustrating, as it's very hard to pin down exactly when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a file called table.layout.js which appeared to be causing this problem. Removing this file cleared stopped the switching.
Something in this was the issue, sorry but I don't have time to debug through it.

```
(function($){
var initLayout = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    var currentTab = $('ul.navigationTabs a')
                        .bind('click', showTab)
                        .filter('a[rel=' + hash + ']');
    if (currentTab.size() == 0) {
        currentTab = $('ul.navigationTabs a:first');
    }
    showTab.apply(currentTab.get(0));
    $('#date').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        date: '2008-07-31',
        current: '2008-07-31',
        calendars: 1,
        starts: 1,
        view: 'years'
    });
    var now = new Date();
    now.addDays(-10);
    var now2 = new Date();
    now2.addDays(-5);
    now2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    $('#date2').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        date: ['2008-07-31', '2008-07-28'],
        current: '2008-07-31',
        format: 'Y-m-d',
        calendars: 1,
        mode: 'multiple',
        onRender: function(date) {
            return {
                disabled: (date.valueOf() < now.valueOf()),
                className: date.valueOf() == now2.valueOf() ? 'datepickerSpecial' : false
            }
        },
        onChange: function(formated, dates) {
        },
        starts: 0
    });
    $('#clearSelection').bind('click', function(){
        $('#date3').DatePickerClear();
        return false;
    });
    $('#date3').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        date: ['2009-12-28','2010-01-23'],
        current: '2010-01-01',
        calendars: 3,
        mode: 'range',
        starts: 1
    });
    $('.inputDate').DatePicker({
        format:'Y-m-d',
        date: $('#inputDate').val(),
        current: $('#inputDate').val(),
        starts: 1,
        position: 'right',
        onBeforeShow: function(){
            $('#inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('#inputDate').val(), true);
        },
        onChange: function(formated, dates){
            $('#inputDate').val(formated);
            if ($('#closeOnSelect input').attr('checked')) {
                $('#inputDate').DatePickerHide();
            }
        }
    });
    var now3 = new Date();
    now3.addDays(-4);
    var now4 = new Date()
    $('#widgetCalendar').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        format: ' YBd',
        date: [new Date(now3), new Date(now4)],
        calendars: 3,
        mode: 'range',
        starts: 1,
        onChange: function(formated) {

            $('#widgetField span').get(0).innerHTML = formated.join(' -- ');
                            // Custom
                gDateFr=formated[0].substring(1); gDateTo=formated[1];

                       }
    });
    var state = false;
    $('#widgetField>a').bind('click', function(){
        $('#widgetCalendar').stop().animate({height: state ? 0 : $('#widgetCalendar div.datepicker').get(0).offsetHeight}, 500);
        state = !state;
        return false;
    });
    $('#widgetCalendar div.datepicker').css('position', 'absolute');
};

var showTab = function(e) {
    var tabIndex = $('ul.navigationTabs a')
                        .removeClass('active')
                        .index(this);
    $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .blur();
    $('div.tabc')
        .hide()
            .eq(tabIndex)
            .show();
};

EYE.register(initLayout, 'init');
```

})(jQuery)